# C# Autofac error Could not load type 'IBaseService`1' from assembly 'Services, when declare two types generic class: IBaseService<T, O>

Tags: c#, autofac

Error occur:

> Could not load type 'Services.IBaseService`1' from assembly 'Services, Version=....

I try with single generic type (`IBaseService< T >`), it works fine.

Could anyone help me how to inject this kind of generic object please?

---

My Interface: (My Impl: (namespace Services.Interface))

```
public interface IBaseService<T, O> where T : class where O: class
{
}

public interface IInvoiceService : IBaseService<Invoice, OInvoice>
{
}
```

---

My Impl: (namespace Services.Impl)

```
public class BaseService<T, O> where T: class where O: class
{
}

public class InvoiceService : BaseService<Invoice, OInvoice>, IInvoiceService
{
}
```

---

My Inject code:

```
...
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(InvoiceService));
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(x => x.Namespace != null 
                   && x.Namespace.EndsWith("Services.Impl"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
...
```

Comment: Is OInvoice a different class than Invoice?

Comment: Yes, OInvoice is different. These classes work with pair of 2 objects(Ex: Internal Invoice vs External Invoice)

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace of the exception and also the inner exception if any ?

Comment: Finally, i figure out my issue. I have 3 projects: API + Service + Auth. Service.dll is added as reference library in API and Auth. I upgrade code from BaseService < T > to BaseService < T , O > in Service proj and copy dll to API but forget to update dll in Auth proj. When Autofac resolve Objects in Auth.dll, it shows me this error.
After update dll in Auth, it work fine :)
Thank you all!